# Loading application.properties file from traditional bean configuration xml with variable file path

Tags: java, spring, jenkins, spring-boot

I am working on a conversion project from spring app to spring-boot (1.52) application with minimal changes –
I have imported bean.xml (bean config xml) in the application bootstrap file, enabled log4J2 logging and used Jersey instead of RestEasy for exposing REST endpoints, everything working. However, I have faced an issue while deploying with Jenkins.  In the bean.xml file of the traditional app has  context:property-placeholder like

```
<context:property-placeholder location="${apps.config.dir:classpath:conf}/myapp.properties" />
```

In the tomcat environment configuration file variable, we have replaced with

```
-Dapps.config.dir=file:/etc/my-app
```

Which is working file. But in the Spring Boot application, I have tried-

```
<context:property-placeholder location="${spring.config.location:classpath:}application.properties"/>
```

I have renamed application.properties so Spring Boot automatically picks the configuration file and also changed the location. The above location also works without classpath keyword in the IDE. One notable change from the tradition spring app is additional “:” without which IDE fails to load the config file from bean.xml file. In the myapp.conf file I have passed following java options 
`-Dapps.config.dir=file:/etc/my-app/` which is failing with following error message (this time I did not place / before application.properties file name and placed additional  / is placed as java options, I have also tried the opposite one but produced the same result)

```
2017-04-24-10:51:26:803|main|ERROR|SpringApplication|Application startup failed application.properties (No such file or directory)onException: Could not load properties; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: /etc/my-app/
```

I am also excluding application.properties file during Jenkins build.

But if I manually change to file rather than classpath and do not pass any java options that one works but my IDE fails as I haven’t placed in in data folder –

```
<context:property-placeholder location="${spring.config.location:file:}application.properties"/>
```

This configuration is not useful as other developers need to change be to run it in their IDE. I want to make it flexible so that it works seamlessly in by IDE and Jenkins build like currently, we have the spring app.  I need help to reconfigure bean.xml variable path to load application.properties file. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you specify the default properties with `SpringApplication.setDefaultProperties`, these properties should be ok for IDE/DEV env. When running elsewhere you could specify an override with `-Dspring.config.location=/etc/my-app/my-conf.properties`

If you still need a property resolver in the xml try to ignore lookup failure like this:
`<context:property-placeholder location="${spring.config.location}" ignore-resource-not-found="true"/>`

For reference in property loading in spring boot see [this part of the doc.](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)

Comment: Hi @Pär thanks for your response. I have used following xml property resolver as an workaround <context:property-placeholder location="application.properties, file:application.properties" ignore-resource-not-found="true" ignore-unresolvable="true"/>

Comment: @Nazrul Be aware that the `@PropertySource` has priority 16 in the property loading and `application.properties` have priority 15. Which means that you cannot override properties in `application.properties` with a `@PropertySource`